# Look through 2 different cameras in 2 different viewport?

Tags: camera, lighting

I want one viewport viewing through one camera and another viewport viewing my scene through another camera. How can I do that?

Right now Blender will switch both viewports to active cameras.

I need to do it this way since I'm tweaking my lighting and I want to make sure my object will look good from different angles as I'm rendering it through both cameras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Turns out you do it by toggling this Local Camera function ON.